# Why does it go into an infinite loop when you write (char c=0;c<256;c++)?

Tags: c++, c

This is how the code is:

```
for(char c=0;c<256;c++)
  printf("hello");
```

Why does this go into an infinite loop?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Comment: @KARTHIK RAO: Don't forget to accept an answer by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

This is because `char` is an 8-bit integer in your case.

So `char` only has the values `-128` to `127`, which is always less than `256`.

Comment: `unsigned char` would have the same problem too, no? 0-255.

Comment: Correct. For unsigned, it will be between `0` to `255`. And will wrap back to zero when it overflows.

Comment: It should be noted that `char` can be either signed or unsigned, and will of course loop indefinitely in either case.

Comment: If we want to be really pedantic a `char` could even be more than 8 bits. It must be the smallest type, but there is no requirement on how small that is.

Comment: @Chris: No, if `char` is signed, the loop will invoke UB; in particular, it **could** terminate.

Answer (score 6):

It's likely that your `char` data type is limitied to eight bits. If the default `char` is signed, eight-bit and you're using twos'complement, it will always be in the range `-128..127` so will always be less than 256.

If it's *unsigned* eight-bit (where the encoding doesn't matter since that only affects signed numbers), it will be always in the `0.255` range so that will also always be under 256.

Note that C doesn't mandate two's complement so the range may change a little but with all possibilities of encoding and only eight bits, the highest value it can have is `255`.

Only if you have more than eight bits available to you will a `char` ever be able to reach 256. This is possible because C only mandates the *minimum* number of bits. You can check what your implementation provides by looking for `CHAR_BITS` in `<limits.h>` but, in the vast majority of cases, this will be 8.

For completeness, the eight-bit range for the three possible C encodiding is:

```
                        signed      unsigned
                        =========   ========
one's complement        -127..127   0..255
sign/magnitude          -127..127   0..255
two's complement        -128..127   0..255
```

Comment: It's a small thing, but does it really make sense in the second paragraph to say "unsigned two's complement"?

Comment: Good point, @murgatroid99, fixed that up.

Answer (score 3):

`char` can only store the values from 0 to 255 if it is unsigned or -128 to 127 if it is signed, which depends on your build settings.  In either case, it will always be less than 256.  Adding one to the highest value will make it wrap around to the lowest value.

Comment: The range of values that a `char` can store is implementation defined. The OP happens to be using one where `char` is 8-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping the byte. Basically when you go over the maximum amount that a variable type can store it will wrap around and begin again from the start.

256 isn't the maximum number a char can hold. It is the maximum number of possible values that a char can represent, those are 2 very different things.

A char is 8 bits (on just about all normal implementations)

A 8 bit type can hold 256 possible distinct values. But for a normal signed char, those possible values are in the range of -128 to 127.

An unsigned char is still 8 bits and therefore holds 256 possible values but those values are in the range of 0 to 255. This is still 1 number off 256 as 0 is a possible value.